# The reduce method on an array, which can be either a regular array or a read-only array

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an array as an argument. This array can be either a regular array or a read-only array.

```
type Item = 'foo' | 'bar';

const func = (arr: Item[] | readonly Item[]) => { // ... };
```

And I want to call the `.reduce` method on this array with the accumulator.

```
type Item = 'foo' | 'bar';

const func = (arr: Item[] | readonly Item[]) => 
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({ ...acc, [item]: item }), {});
  //          ^? (parameter) acc: Item
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oHIBmB7LaoB90AjAQwCc0BuAWACg7RIoB5IgKxSgAVzgBLEgBsAPACUIAYyxkAJsLiIANFAB2AVwREIZAHw6a9WlJUBnYFAxqVEgIycAFH3gITALljOA2gF0AlO9YOZB0oAG86KChjMyh4GNQnRBMAOjIIGTUJCGFAnXsIyKh7EgkJZUSEXxQQ+1Dk+pKyqE8K73cABgBfX2UCyNDOgt8DArTgNTIVWIgzA0GjLFNzS2sAJgcKtyg0khlFwRAPRB9-FnZqsILo8zjzBOcUtIysnPY8vqLG8ucq4KK6hqlZQtZxtKBdHpQD4DIYjWiRMYTKa3OZ0OjXCxWCQAZg2D3cCgQPgI2wgu32h0JJwC5z+4XhUUWMVunE2qXSmWyuXyDMixSBUAqvxqAOSX2arQ63V6vLC80iwzRDMRk2mszonSAA)

And for some reason TS types `acc` with the wrong type. TS thinks the accumulator is an `Item` from the array, but it should be an object.

The error dissapears when the arg parameter is typed as arr: Item[] or arr: readonly Item[].
But I want to use this reducer on both arrays.

Edit:
How to fix this error?

@jonrsharpe answered how to fix - you don't need to specify union type of the `arr`.
`(arr: readonly Item[]) => { //... }` would be sufficient for both regular arrays and read-only arrays.

Comment: `readonly Item[]` would surely also permit a mutable array, though? https://tsplay.dev/mpzyBw

Comment: What's the specific question here? Are you asking why it doesn't work, or how to write it so it does work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe is correct. If you declare your parameter to be readonly, it means that any array will be considered immutable inside the function: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhgJwKZwCbgDYE8ZgCuAtgEarIDaAujALwyUCMANDAExsDM1A3ALAAoUJFikkMSVKlEyFGvUasO3PkKEAzECAAUcAJS8YAemMwA8gGlN2naUMmzV9YI2EwwKAEtwMLbrhkZCQ0TBx8WXIqan0YAG8hSUDkADoAB0IIAAsdABZ2B1MKZBBkIQBfISA)

Comment: > Why it doesn't work, or how to write it so it does work? 

Both, but I think @jonrsharpe answered how to fix it.

Comment: Both? [That's two questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366). Could you pick one? Otherwise, if, say, @jonrsharpe knows how to fix it but not why, and I know why but don't suggest the best way to fix it, then which answer is "correct"?  Of course any answer would probably end up addressing both to some extent, but there should be a single well-defined question so that it is clear what constitutes an actual answer to the question as asked.  Could you please [edit] the post to ask a single clearly-articulated question?

Comment: @jcalz I'd be really curious why this doesn't work, or why TypeScript does no longer permit passing a type parameter for `reduce` if the method is called on a union (as in the playground linked by the OP)

Comment: @Bergi it's https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50488.  Overloads lose their overloadness when manipulated.

Comment: Despite the provided warning (_"Spread types may only be created from object types."_) related to ... `({...acc, [item]: 0})`, ... `Object.assign(acc, { [item]: 0 } )` ... does not. How come?

Comment: ? There are a bunch of warnings, and the salient one is the fact the overload that supports having the accumulator be a different type from the array element is gone.  The array element is `Item`, a string, so TS thinks you're spreading a string.  At this point I'm going to disengage from explaining things in comments and I'll just wait to see if the question officially becomes "why is this happening". Good luck all.

Comment: @jcalz thanks, that makes sense (or, not really, but the bug report explains what's happening). So due to the union, it chooses the wrong overload, the one where the accumulator is typed the same as the element type and not a generic that might be passed or inferred.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
Please, post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.